# Laravel : db - Update operation not working?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, sql-update, laravel-8, rest

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request,$id){  
        
        $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                
                'orderId'    => 'required|integer',
                'fileId'    => 'required|integer',
                'status'    => 'required|string'
            ]
        );

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
        }

        $data=FileLogs::find($id)->update(['$data->orderId'=>'$request->orderId','$data->fileId'=>'$request->fileId','$data->status'=>'$request->status']);
        return response()->json(['status'=>'success','StatusCode'=> 200,'message'=>'Successfully Updated','data'=>$data]);
   }
```

The code is not working for `update` operation,but it is working in the below method. However , i want to do the `update` operation by calling `update` directly on the model as given above since the `updated` events can't be triggered without doing so. I'm using laarvel-8. Pls help me to make the above work.

```
$data = FileLogs::find($id); 
            if($data){
               $data->orderId=$request->orderId;
               $data->fileId=$request->fileId;
               $data->status=$request->status;
               $data->update();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove quotes from $request and also don't add variables to key

```
$data=FileLogs::find($id)->update([
                                   'orderId'=>$request->orderId,
                                   'fileId'=>$request->fileId,
                                   'status'=>$request->status
                                  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write `$data->XY` in your array. You simply have to use the column names as keys. You also don't have to escape the request values otherwise you are just assigning strings:

```
$data= FileLogs::find($id)->update([
'orderId'=>$request->orderId,
'fileId'=>$request->fileId,
'status'=>$request->status
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$data->` from all of your `'$data->...'` and the quotes from all of your `'$request->...'`.

```
$data=FileLogs::find($id)->update([
   'orderId' => $request->orderId,
   'fileId' => $request->fileId,
   'status' => $request->status,
]);
```